# Adding sheets to end of workbook in Excel (normal method not working?)

Tags: vba, excel

This is the VBA code im using to try add a new sheet to the last place in the workbook

```
mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = new_sheet_name
```

I saw this in a similar question on this site. Its not working.

I do this in a loop and each sheet gets added to the second position in the sheets. There are 2 sheets that are permanently there (info and summary) and I then precede to add 5 more called "test" 1 through 5. I always end up with the sheets in this order:

```
Info, sheet5, sheet4, sheet3, sheet2, sheet1, Summary
```

But what I want/was expecting was:

```
Info, Summary, sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4, sheet5
```

(the loop does produce them in the expected order so the problem isn't there.)

If I swap the summary and info sheets before I start then they are in the opposite places when I'm done.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this

```
mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=mainWB.Sheets(mainWB.Sheets.Count)).Name = new_sheet_name
```

Comment: ok, that works....but I was only using one workbook in the first place so why was that causing a problem?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you have at least 2 WBs open. Can you double check? Which WB is `mainWB` referring to?

Comment: oh wait...nevermind, i forgor the CSV files the macro was opening. Thanks...again...you seem to have answered 50% of my questions XD

Comment: which other 50% is remaining? :)

Comment: @Jacxel, if your code still isn't working, your loop or something else isn't right. Siddharth, Tim, and Gimp's answers should solve your problem.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry you misunderstood me, I meant you you HAVE answered about 50% of my questionS on SE.

Answer (score 7):

```
mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = new_sheet_name
```

should probably be

```
mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=mainWB.Sheets(mainWB.Sheets.Count)).Name = new_sheet_name
```

Comment: + 1 None the less for posting at the same time :)

Answer (score 3):

A common mistake is

```
mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets.Count)
```

which leads to Error 1004. Although it is not clear at all from the official documentation, it turns out that the 'After' parameter cannot be an integer, it must be a reference to a sheet in the same workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to fully qualify your sheets with which workbook they are referencing!

```
 mainWB.Sheets.Add(After:=mainWB.Sheets(mainWB.Sheets.Count)).Name = new_sheet_name
```