# Adding Excel Sheets to End of Workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com

I am trying to add excel worksheets to the end of a workbook, reserving the first sheet for a summary.

```
import win32com.client

Excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add()

Excel.Visible = True

Book.Worksheets(3).Delete()
Book.Worksheets(2).Delete()

Sheet = Book.Worksheets(1)

Sheet.Name = "Summary"

Book.Worksheets.Add(After=Sheet)

Sheet = Book.Worksheets(2)

Sheet.Name = "Data1"
```

This code adds the new sheet to the left, despite using `After=Sheet`, and when I modify the sheet named "Data1", it overwrites the sheet named "Summary".

This is similar to this problem:

[Adding sheets to end of workbook in Excel (normal method not working?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456157/adding-sheets-to-end-of-workbook-in-excel-normal-method-not-working)

but the given solutions don't work for me.

Comment: Instead of `After = Sheet`, try `After = Sheets.Count` (I'm not too keen on PythonVBA, but you want to make sure you add it after the last sheet.

Comment: What happens when you try the given solutions?

Comment: Neither `After=Book.Worksheets.Count` nor `After=Book.Sheets(Book.Sheets.Count)` work. They give the same behavior described above.

Comment: Another interesting anomaly is that when I use `Sheet.Move(After = Sheets.Count)` or similar, it moves Sheet to a new workbook.

Comment: In VBA I use `Sheets.Add, Sheets(Sheets.Count)` as my shortcut to add a worksheet at the end... so *'that'* in Python. (I think you just need to add three `book` objects in this case.)

Answer (score 16):

Try using this by adding `Before = None`:

```
add = Book.Sheets.Add(Before = None , After = Book.Sheets(book.Sheets.count))
add.Name = "Data1"
```

Comment: @PPotreus, this is the answer you were looking for. Accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Where was Sheets defined in the original post?

Comment: .Count should be with capital C

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Sheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet`:

```
Book.Worksheets.Add(After=Sheet)
Sheet = Book.ActiveSheet
Sheet.Name = "Data1"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the new sheet still doesn't appear to the right of the existing sheet.

Answer (score -1):

import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Sheets.Add(After=xl.ActiveSheet).Name ="Name_of_your_Sheet"