# Move a worksheet in a workbook using openpyxl or xl* or xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlwt

I've read the docs for, [openpyxl](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openpyxl/latest/openpyxl.pdf), [xlwt](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xlwt/latest/xlwt.pdf), [xlrd](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xlrd/latest/xlrd.pdf), [xlutils](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xlutils/latest/xlutils.pdf), [xlsxwriter](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xlsxwriter/latest/xlsxwriter.pdf). I don't find a way to move a sheet in an **Excel workbook**. Tests added a worksheet to the ends.

Concretely, I have a calendar of sorts, `['JAN','FEB',...,'DEC']` and I need to replace months as the need arises.

How do you order the sheets in an Excel workbook if you don't *move* them? Can you insert a sheet *after* or *before* a specified sheet?

Only one other [post I can find on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179804/adding-excel-sheets-to-end-of-workbook) uses `win32com` and `Book.Worksheets.Add(After=Sheet)`; seems strange none of these modules would have this method.

Default seems to add sheet at end of workbook. I could copy the destination file, until the updated sheet is reached,  insert new sheet, and continue original copy to the end. (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook/))

Answer (score 11):

I had two problems. The first problem was inserting a sheet at a given position. The second problem was moving a sheet around. Since I mostly deal with the newer Excel file `xlsx`, then I would be using openpyxl.

Various sources indicate new sheets are added to the end. I expected I would need to do this each time, and then move the sheet. I asked the question *"(How to) move a worksheet..."* thinking this was would solve both problems.

Ultimately, the first problem was easy once I finally found an example which showed `workbook.create_sheet()` method takes an optional `index` argument to insert a new sheet at a given zero-indexed position. (I really have to learn to look at the code, because the [answer was here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html)):

```
 def create_sheet(self, title=None, index=None):
        """Create a worksheet (at an optional index)
        [...]
```

Next. Turns out you can move a sheet by reordering the Workbook container `_sheets`. So I made a little helper func to test the idea:

```
def neworder(shlist, tpos = 3):
    """Takes a list of ints, and inserts the last int, to tpos location (0-index)"""
    lst = []
    lpos = (len(shlist) - 1)
    print("Before:", [x for x in range(len(shlist))])
    # Just a counter
    for x in range(len(shlist)):
        if x > (tpos - 1) and x != tpos:
            lst.append(x-1)
        elif x == tpos:
            lst.append(lpos)
        else:
            lst.append(x)

    return lst

# Get the sheets in workbook
currentorder = wb.sheetnames
# move the last sheet to location `tpos`
myorder = neworder(currentorder)

>>>Before: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
>>>After : [0, 1, 2, 17, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

# get each object instance from  wb._sheets, and replace
wb._sheets = [wb._sheets[i] for i in myorder]
```

The first answer was not hard to spot in the openpyxl documentation once I realized what it did. Just a bit surprised more blogs didn't mention moving sheets around.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I came up with (using openpyxl)

```
def move_sheet(wb, from_loc=None, to_loc=None):
    sheets=wb._sheets

    # if no from_loc given, assume last sheet
    if from_loc is None:
        from_loc = len(sheets) - 1

    #if no to_loc given, assume first
    if to_loc is None:
        to_loc = 0

    sheet = sheets.pop(from_loc)
    sheets.insert(to_loc, sheet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Complement to [xtian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573582/13604080) solution, with option to move the worksheet from any position to any place forward or backwards.

```
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def neworder(file, fpos, tpos):
    """Takes a list of ints, and inserts the fpos (from position) int, to tpos (to position)"""
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
    shlist = wb.sheetnames  # get current order sheets in workbook
    lst = []
    lpos = (len(shlist) - 1) # last position
    if lpos >= fpos > tpos >= 0:  # move from a high to low position
        for x in range(lpos+1):
            if x == tpos:
                lst.append(fpos)
            elif tpos < x <= fpos:
                lst.append(x-1)
            else:
                lst.append(x)
    if lpos >= tpos > fpos >= 0:  # move from a low to high position
        for x in range(lpos+1):
            if x == tpos:
                lst.append(fpos)
            elif fpos <= x < tpos:
                lst.append(x+1)
            else:
                lst.append(x)
    wb._sheets = [wb._sheets[i] for i in lst]  # get each object instance from  wb._sheets, and replace
    wb.save(filename=file)
    return


filex = Path('C:/file.xlsx')
neworder(filex, 83, 12)  # move worksheet in 83rd position to 12th position
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is for basic moving of sheets. I am using move_sheets function in openpyxl

Say you have sheets named Sheet 1 : "abc" and Sheet 2: "xyz" and you want to move xyz from 2nd position to first

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_worksheet("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testfile.xlsx") #load worksheet using the excel file path, make sure you load the file from correct path
wb.active = 1 #the sheet index starts from 0 , hence 1 will select the second sheet ie xyz
wb.move_sheet(wb.active, offset = -1) #this will offset the current active sheet which is xyz be one position to the left which in our case is 1st position
wb.save(//path where you want to save the file.xlsx)
```