# Sheets.Add returns a 1004 Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I used this example, as follows, from Microsoft Docs website and received the message `Sheets.Add returns a 1004 Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed`.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
```

Please advise solution.

Comment: You code seems okay. `Sheet` is a reserve keyword. Avoid it and use another name like `sht`.

Comment: Check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11456157/5514747

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't use 'sheet' as a variable name
2. `After:=` requires a sheet object, not a number

Could be

```
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)))
```

Sorry if errors in code, written on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet` is reserved keyword. So, try another name using below sub.

```
Sub addsh()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

To add a sheet with name use below sub.

```
Sub addsh()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = "MyNewSheet"
End Sub
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456178/5514747) from @Siddharth

Comment: Created and ran 'Sub addsh() as advised. No 1004 error but sheet "MyNewSheet" was not created in the active workbook.

Comment: Strange behavior. Can you test codes to a new workbook?

Comment: Created new workbook and reran code with exactly the same result, i.e. no 1004 error but new sheet not created. BTW each time I run the code, I have to change the name as I am informed that 'the sheet name is already in use - use a different one"

Comment: You have to use a variable for sheet name. Otherwise run first codes to add default sheet name.

Comment: OK, got it; thanks. Had code in PERSONAL.XLSB instead of ThisWorkbook;

Comment: Sheet is not a reserved word, any more than Cell is.

Comment: Have now resolved the code location issue and the code, as follows, works a treat; thank you.

Comment: Dim wb As Workbook
    
        Set wb = Workbooks(CSVFilename)
        
        wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "m-d-yyyy h_mm_ss am/pm")
        
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Transposed"